# SignalR with custom Authentication and authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub

I have Three applications.

1)Windows Application

2)Asp.net web form

3)Asp.net MVC

I have a Authentication and Authorization system that implemented using a web service. In simple form the underlying tables are like:

```
 User Table:

     Id        UserName       Password       
     ---------------------------------

 Role Table;
    
     Id          RoleName
     ---------------------------------

 UserRole

     UserId        RoleId
     ---------------------------------
```

Now I want to implement a chat capability for these apps. My problem is I don't know how to integrate `SignalR` with my custom authentication. Consider this scenario that a user wants to send a message to another user:

```
public async Task SendMessage(string user1, string user2, string message)
```

this method works find in first glance. But how can I prevent this scenario:

> if `user3` knows `user1` username and create a request and send a message from `user1` to `user2`?

Since I can't change my auth service to user Asp.net Identity and integrate it with SignalR How can I be sure that the logged in user send the message and no one can do impersonation?

Could any body help me to get the correct idea and plan?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the official documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz

Comment: @VladDX, Yes I have but it describe Asp.net Identity or Token based auth. I want to completely custom auth integrate with my signalr chat

Comment: [Policy based authorization](https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2020/march/custom-signalr-hub-authorization-in-aspnet-core/) should useful to you.

Comment: Do you want to chat in a way similar to a social networking website, where members have to log in to access it?

Comment: you would use **HubFilter** to autheticate user(get UserName from token ). check this link https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/signalr/hub-filters.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a custom authorization attribute where you do the necessary checks and reject unauthorised users /accept authorised users. You could then decorate the desired hub classes/methods with the custom authorization attribute.

You should find this answer to a similar question helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14343581/19214431.

Answer (score 2):

You have different kind of client application. So I recommend to use Bearer token for authentication. The client app should add a bearer token to the request that send to the server. I don't know which version of .net do you use but it is easy to configure using .net core.

In web app:

```
this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/hubs/chat", { accessTokenFactory: () => this.loginToken })
    .build();
```

In the Windows app

```
var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl("https://example.com/chathub", options =>
    { 
        options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(_myAccessToken);
    })
    .Build();
```

Note that the identity server should provide the token to the client. I see you implemented your identity server. Using the built-in library like Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity and Entityframework Core would have made life easier in this case. Also using IdentityServer is an option. Otherwise you need to implement and develop your custom IdentityServer that provide access token to clients.

[Authentication and authorization in ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

[Using IdentityServer](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

[Creating And Validating JWT Tokens In C# .NET](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/01/15/creating-and-validating-jwt-tokens-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: I'm reading theis documentation, but I don't know how I can get the "_myAccessToken" in this line: Task.FromResult(_myAccessToken)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which version of .net you use
but I try .net core 6.

you can try is **The Context object**
because Gets the unique ID for the connection, assigned by SignalR. There's one connection ID for each connection.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-6.0

I try to Save the ID and message then judge if the Items have key is ok.

you can try unique ID  be sure that the logged-in user sends the message and no one can do an impersonation.

**ChatHub.cs**

```
 public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            string getID = Context.ConnectionId;
            DateTime time=DateTime.Now;

            var data = Context.Items.Where(o => o.Key == getID).ToList();
            int dataCount = Context.Items.Count();
            if (dataCount==0)
            {
                Context.Items.Add(getID,time);
            }else{
                Context.Abort();//Aborts the connection.
                 //you code
            }

         await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);

        }


    }
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem is, every time a user close the browser and open egain, he/she obtain a new connection id